# Searching for phrases like "ABC DEF" but allowing distance between "ABC" and "DEF"

Tags: python, mysql, pattern-matching

I'm trying to filter a table of research abstracts into ones that are more related to the topic "RNA sequencing".

```
SELECT * FROM RNAseq
WHERE 
    MATCH (abstract_text) AGAINST ('"use RNAseq" "use RNA-seq" "use RNA"' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

However, this leaves out sentences like "I will use x, y, and RNA-seq...". Is there a way to `MATCH AGAINST ('"use +upto200char+ RNA-seq"')`, AKA search for instances when "use" is within a certain distance (200 characters in the example) from "RNA-seq"? I figure this will probably have to be done in python b/c as far as I'm concerned MySQL doesn't have this capability.

Comment: I would try SELECT * FROM RNAseq WHERE abstract_textREGEXP '(use)+.*(RNA)+.*';  It is not owerfect and will give some false positives as NIck pointed out https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4078645294cf7f3b4d2f70be3328931c  But to be honest two 3 letter words with something between them isn't the best search pattern anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BOOLEAN MODE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) searching using a "distance" measure (specified with `@`) to get the results you want, although you have to specify the distance between `use` and `RNA` in words, rather than characters. This query looks for any of the sequences `use RNA`, `use RNA-seq` or `use RNAseq` with up to 18 words (the two words are included in the distance measure) between them:

```
SELECT *
FROM RNAseq
WHERE MATCH abstract_text AGAINST('"use RNAseq" @20 "use RNA" @20 "use RNA-seq" @20' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```